# How do I iteratively show on click a selection value, a div or another div?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, hidden

I have a problem in iteratively displaying a div, on the click of a selected value.

When I select the disease Pancreatitis or Glycemia, I display "We are sorry but for this disease, you must consult a doctor" and when I choose `Nothing`, I display "It's ok". By default, I have to show "it's ok".

I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-md-12 malattie" onchange="change(this)" id="malattie">
    <label>Are you affected by one of the following conditions?
    <select id="malattie">
        <option value="Nothing">Nothing</option>
        <option value="Pancreatitis">Pancreatitis</option>
        <option value="Glycemia">Glycemia</option>
    </select>
    <div id="alert"></div>
    <div id="form_nodisease">It's ok</div>
    <script>
        function change(myselect){
            if(myselect !="Nothing"){
                document.getElementById("form_nodisease").style.display = 'none'; 
                document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="We are sorry but for this disease you must consult a doctor"
            }else{
                document.getElementById("form_nodisease").style.display = 'block'; 
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on Pancreatitis or Glycemia, I correctly show "We are sorry but for this disease, you must consult a doctor", but when I click on Nothing, I still see "We are sorry but for this disease, you must consult a doctor" instead of "It's ok".

It is like it doesn't recognize the change in selection value. How do I iteratively show a selection value, a div, or another div on click?

Comment: Also note that the `div#malattie` has no end tag in your given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```js
function change(myselect) {
  if (myselect.value != "Nothing") {
    document.getElementById("form_nodisease").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("alert").style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    document.getElementById("form_nodisease").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("alert").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 malattie">
  <label>Are you affected by one of the following conditions?
    <select id="malattie" onchange="change(this)">
      <option value="Nothing">Nothing</option>
      <option value="Pancreatitis">Pancreatitis</option>
      <option value="Glycemia">Glycemia</option>
    </select>
    <div id="alert" style="display: none;">We are sorry but for this disease you must consult a doctor</div>
    <div id="form_nodisease">It's ok</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

I have made some changes, for example you had a duplicate id, and the text of the alert is written at the beginning but depending on what you select, it is displayed or not.

Answer (score 2):

The `onChange` attribute was not at the correct place and you need to check for `myselect.value`.

I have also removed `alert` and just changed the `innerHTML` of the `form_nodisease` class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12 malattie" id="malattie">
<label>Are you affected by one of the following conditions?
<select id=malattie onchange="change(this)">
    <option value="Nothing">Nothing</option>
    <option value="Pancreatitis">Pancreatitis</option>
    <option value="Glycemia">Glycemia</option>
</select>
<div id="form_nodisease">It's ok</div>
<script>
function change(myselect){
if(myselect.value !="Nothing"){
  document.getElementById("form_nodisease").innerHTML="We are sorry but for this disease you must consult a doctor" 
}else{  
  document.getElementById("form_nodisease").innerHTML="ok!"
}}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```